# Align dynamically created textview and edit text in android

Tags: android, alignment, layoutparams

I have a relative layout and 'n' number of textviews and edittext . I want the alignment as

```
  TextView   EditText
       Button
  TextView   EditText
        Button
   TextView   EditText
         Button
  TextView   EditText
        Button
  ..........
```

I have tried using layout params but I am getting weird results.
Here is my code,

```
 RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutid);
    final TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[41];
    for (int i = 0; i < 41; i++) {
        // create a new textview
        rowTextView = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsA = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        paramsA.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, rowTextView.getId());
        rowTextView.setId(i);
        // add the textview to the layout
        relativeLayout.addView(rowTextView, paramsA);
        myTextViews[i] = rowTextView;

    }
```

For Edit Text..

```
    final EditText[] editTextarray = new EditText[41];
    for (int i = 0; i < 41; i++) {
        // create a new textview
        final EditText editText = new EditText(this); 
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsB = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         editText.setText("edit");
        editText.setCursorVisible(true);
        relativeLayout.addView(editText, paramsB);
        editTextarray[i] = editText;

    }
```

I have applied layout_params like this but it didn't help. Any help would be great!! Thanks

Comment: Why did not you use linear layout here?

Comment: Do you want me to use linear layout without using params ? Its dynamically generated . How can I have linear layout ? It will generate around 100 edit text dynamically @SohailZahid

Comment: if you are not using relative layout properties then simply use linear layout with orientation.

Comment: And for performance concerns you can add your Editext and TextView both in single loop.

Comment: If I use linear layout with horizontal orientation then my output will be like edittext edittext edittext............. @SohailZahid

Comment: yes it be like this.

Comment: I don't want so !! So, what are you about to say ? @SohailZahid

Comment: if it is dynamic, why you're not using listView? Create one row layout with your specific format and then add items to it according to your requirements

Comment: I don't want to make it complicated. Thought could be completed via params @YasirTahir

Comment: @Anusha why did not you use list view if your view are identical.

Comment: @Anusha still you can get your desire result you linear layout Add to linear layout like this textview  edittext textview  edittext textview  edittext....

Comment: I think this one is complicated and this is not the right way to do if you have exact same rows with exact same elements. You should create listView.

Comment: @Anusha i have made some change in your code might help you.

Answer (score 1):

add the layout

layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="textview"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Edittex"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="button"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

add this layout at run time:

```
    View view;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

   for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {

     view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
     linearLayout.addView(view);
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to pass the dynamic values to the text view now ? @Pradeep Gupta

Comment: add this in for loop TextView tvBuy = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);tvBuy .setText("your Value");

Comment: Its showing error in (LayoutInflator) expression expected @Pradeep Gupta

Comment: And what's that linear layout ? LinearLayout's id? @Pradeep Gupta

Comment: i had edit the code please check and linearlayout is id which is in your xml.

Comment: I am trying @Pradeep Gupta

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110988/discussion-between-anusha-and-pradeep-gupta).

Comment: It showing only one edit text , text view and button
I want all the 41 to display

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use custom layout and inflate it programmatically.

create a layout consist of `TextView` , `EditText` and `Button` with your desired output and inflate it.

```
View v=LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.customLayout,null);
```

and use variable `v` to refer `TextView` , `EditText` and `Button`.

your `customLayout.xml` can be something like this :

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Take `LinearLayout` in your xml having orientation vertical, and add this view in that layout to create different views.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customLayout, null);

    ll.addView(v);
}
```

Comment: Can you modify my code and provide as a solution ? @Ravi Rupareliya

Comment: sorry, cannot give you whole code, can give you hint about it. If people will downvote for this than also i will accept it.

Comment: LinearLayout lv = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutid); . Should we access linearlayout using id? Ll in your code is the reference right ?

Comment: here ll is LinearLayout in my main layout, where you are going to add all those views.

Comment: Its displaying only one edit text, text view and button but not all @Ravi Rupareliya

Answer (score 0):

Anusha try this with linearlayout

Still if your design is identical you should use listview best approach.

```
 LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutid);
        final TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[41];
        final EditText[] editTextarray = new EditText[41];
        for (int i = 0; i < 41; i++) {
            // create a new textview
            rowTextView = new TextView(this);
            myTextViews[i] = rowTextView;
            linearLayout.addView(myTextViews[i]);

            final EditText editText = new EditText(this);
            editText.setText("edit");
            editText.setCursorVisible(true);
            editTextarray[i] = editText;
            linearLayout.addView(editTextarray[i]);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to implement ListView for this requirement -

Per your current approach you will end-up setting multiple onClicklisteners for each of your buttons - if that button is going to pick data of the input associated with the textview/edittext - you will end up writing many array calls and stuff

Listview - onclick of any item you can fire one onClickListener where you differentiate

PS: Bad design to repeat button below textview/edittext if the button is expected to perform same/similar function say saving - just have a listview of textview/edittext - a common button action somewhere on the toolbar or below the form.